# How to connect Reactjs and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have created react js as Frontend folder and Laravel as Backend folder.I need to interconnect both laravel and react js. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix)?

Comment: Yeah I have looked that but it's connecting "resources/js/app.js" path file with laravel. I need to connect "front-end\src\index.js" file with laravel

Answer (score -1):

I thing I figured out.Please add following line in webpack.mix.js file. It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: You should use a relative path, or it won't build on other machines (e.g. CI).